# How can I list all the trips from one stop to another using GTFS?

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I am using the below table:

```
1   0051ML66220600132482    06:00:00        06:00:00        1538    100 0   1
2   0051ML66220600132482    06:00:00        06:00:00        1540    200 0   0
3   0051ML66220600132482    06:00:00        06:00:00        1541    300 0   0
4   0051ML66220600132482    06:01:00        06:01:00        1542    400 0   0
5   0051ML66220600132482    06:01:00        06:01:00        1543    500 0   0
6   0051ML66220600132482    06:02:00        06:02:00        1544    600 0   0
7   0051ML66220600132482    06:03:00        06:03:00        1546    700 0   0
```

Table structure us like below:

```
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> --  TABLE stop_times
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> CREATE TABLE stop_times ( id int(12),
>                           trip_id varchar(100),
>                           arrival_time varchar(8),
>                           arrival_time_seconds int(100),
>                           departure_time varchar(8),
>                           departure_time_seconds int(100),
>                           stop_id varchar(100),
>                           stop_sequence varchar(100),
>                           pickup_type varchar(2),
>                           drop_off_type varchar(2) );
```

I am attempting to get DISTINCT `trip_id` is it matches both the destination and arrival `stop_id`

I have tried the below SQL with no luck:

```
select DISTINCT trip_id from stop_times where stop_id=1538 AND stop_id =1540;
```

Where is should produce: `0051ML66220600132482`

I have also tried a INNER JOIN SQL like below:

```
SELECT 
       t.trip_id,
       start_s.stop_name as departure_stop,
       end_s.stop_name as arrival_stop
FROM
trips t 
        INNER JOIN stop_times start_st ON t.trip_id = start_st.trip_id
        INNER JOIN stops start_s ON start_st.stop_id = start_s.stop_id
        INNER JOIN stop_times end_st ON t.trip_id = end_st.trip_id
        INNER JOIN stops end_s ON end_st.stop_id = end_s.stop_id
WHERE 
   start_s.stop_id = 1538 
  AND end_s.stop_id = 1540;
```

But it is sooo slow, and takes about 8-15 seconds for this simple query.

Explain Added:

[image]

What is the fastest/Best way to make this query?

Comment: provide explain plan for your query

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Explain Added.

Comment: You've provided 8 columns of data but 10 columns in the `CREATE`.

Comment: @EternalHour that's right. I was going to use those columns later. Does that effect the query significantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in other words, you are looking for a query that will identify all the trips that pass through a pair of stops, the origin (starting point) and destination (ending point).

Try this query:

```
SELECT destination.trip_id
    FROM stop_times AS origin
    INNER JOIN stop_times AS destination
        ON destination.trip_id = origin.trip_id
        AND destination.stop_id = 1540
    WHERE origin.stop_id = 1538
        AND origin.stop_sequence < destination.stop_sequence;
```

Or, for a prettier view (and to match the second query in your question):

```
SELECT destination.trip_id, origin_stop.name, destination_stop.name
    FROM stop_times AS origin
    INNER JOIN stop_times AS destination
        ON destination.trip_id = origin.trip_id
        AND destination.stop_id = 1540
    INNER JOIN stops AS origin_stop
        ON origin_stop.id = origin.stop_id
    INNER JOIN stops AS destination_stop
        ON destination_stop.id = destination.stop_id
    WHERE origin.stop_id = 1538
        AND origin.stop_sequence < destination.stop_sequence;
```

For good performance, create an index first on `stop_id` and `trip_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX stop_times_stop_id_trip_id_index ON stop_times(stop_id, trip_id);
```

(Note that EternalHour's query identifies all the trips that pass through *either* stop, not only trips that pass through one first and then the other.)

Comment: You right, Ethernals query doesn't work correctly. I need a trip that passes through both stops. Your works great, but it is slow. Even with the index

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the query you need. I took out `DISTINCT` and replaced it with `GROUP BY` and also replaced the `WHERE` with `IN`. Your query indicates that `stop_id` should be of type `INT`, not `varchar` since you had not added quotes to it, the fiddle reflects that.

The `IN` basically does an `OR` instead of an `AND`. Nothing will be returned with `AND` since both `stop_id`'s don't exist on the same row.

```
SELECT trip_id 
FROM stop_times 
WHERE stop_id IN(1538,1540)
GROUP BY trip_id
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57e75/3)

Comment: Do you need the query to return a separate row for each `stop_id`?